# Error -1501 - any ideas? - InstallShield "Basic MSI" Projects?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, installshield

Can anyone help, the error I'm getting when I try to build a release? The error from the logs is as below:

Building .cab files...
ISEXP : error : -1501: Could not compress "F:\Nagarajan\Projects\Game\Game.opensdf" into "F:\Nagarajan\Projects\Game\Game Installer\Game Installer\Express\SingleImage\DiskImages\DISK1\Data1.cab"

Kindly help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Does `Game.opensdf` exist in that location? You might try running a command-line build with `iscmdbld.exe /v ...` to turn on verbose output to help diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `.opensdf` file is a temporary file, used by - and held open by - Visual Studio whiile you have your project open. It should not be part of your distribution, so you just need to remove it from the list of files packed by the installer.

Comment: Roger Rowland - How do I remove those temp files?